# Can I specify a python path for QGIS python console to use?

Tags: pyqgis, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm new in QGIS and I want to use it with python and Google Earth Engine API.
When I run the code like `addLayer`, there is an error like this:

```py
import ee
from ee_plugin import Map

qtp = ee.FeatureCollection("users/zacharyvixx/tp_bd_2021")

Map.addLayer(qtp, {'color':'red'}, "QTP Boundary")
```

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  File "/home/zachary/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/Map.py", line 25, in addLayer
    add_or_update_ee_layer(eeObject, visParams, name, shown, opacity)
  File "/home/zachary/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/utils.py", line 158, in add_or_update_ee_layer
    update_ee_layer_properties(layer, eeObject, visParams, shown, opacity)
  File "/home/zachary/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ee_plugin/utils.py", line 26, in update_ee_layer_properties
    layer.dataProvider().set_ee_object(eeObject)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'QgsRasterDataProvider' object has no attribute 'set_ee_object'
```

At first I thought it might be something else, until I found that the QGIS is using the default python in my Linux system, which is 3.11, and this might be the problem (while I am not sure).

I tried to search for settings on specifying a python path for the QGIS to use, but I don't think I found a workaround for me.